# The SQL query below returns an error. Revise the SQL query.How can you fix it?(0.5 M) SELECT department_id, COUNT(last_name) FROM employees;

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
`employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`department_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`salary` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`commission_pct` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

### --
-- Dumping data for table `employees`

```
INSERT INTO `employees` (`employee_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`,
`department_id`, `salary`, `commission_pct`) VALUES
(10, 'Ahmed', 'Faruq', 101, 2300, 0.25),
(20, 'Sam', 'Smith', 102, 4200, 0.3),
(30, 'Lio', 'King', 103, 1200, NULL),
(40, 'Jesica', 'Alba', 101, 2670, NULL),
(50, 'Frya', 'John', 103, 1700, 0.45),
(60, 'Jack', 'Black', 102, 3400, NULL),
(70, 'Emily', 'smith', 104, 1530, NULL),
(80, 'George', 'Austin', 101, 5670, 0.45),
(90, 'Daniel', 'Lorents', 102, 4120, 0.15),
(100, 'Adam', 'Fripp', 103, 7690, 0.2);
```

hello dear this is for the assignment that I should be submit tommorow, help me please .

The SQL query below returns an error. Revise the SQL query.How can you fix it?(0.5 M)

```
SELECT department_id, COUNT(last_name)
FROM employees;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting RDBMS. The syntax shows that this is clearly MySQL, *not* T-SQL (which is used by SQL Server).

Comment: You are doing an aggregation thus you need to add non-aggregation fields to a group by : SELECT department_id, COUNT(last_name) FROM employees group by department_id;  (And I believe it tells you this in the error message)

Answer (score 0):

You need the use GROUP BY statement.

```
SELECT department_id, Count(last_name)
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a01bf1/7)